# Making all images have the same format

Tags: image

**What I want:** I want to create a catalog for an online shop, in order to show products.
**Issue:** Should I use one single format or just allow the typical `.jpg` `.png` `.gif` ones?
**Theory:** My idea is doing the next: create a file upload where all images are going to be converted into `.jpg` after cheking the [getimagesize()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php) returns **true** *(and forcing all `.jpg` extensions to behave just as what they are with `ForceType image/jpeg` on my .htaccess file)*.
**Question**: is this a reliable way of doing it, or does anyone know a better alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the browser's perspective, it doesn't really matter... .jpg, .png, and .gif are all just handled objects in their memory-space.

If I were to make a suggestion, however, I would probably use JPG as the default, simply because you're likely to get better compression and smaller file sizes for photographic images (which I assume are the subject matter of your products), which will help speed up the browsing experience.

Depending on what server tech you have available, I know that in the Unix-based servers, there is a module that you can install called ImageMagick (sp?), which allows you to perform conversions of images from one format to another, and I know Ruby, Perl, and PHP all have extensions to allow you to integrate with that library available in the common domain. (I'm sure node, Python, etc also have modules for their respective use, too...)

Just my $.02, good luck!